# How to access controller value in custom typeahead templates

Tags: angularjs, bootstrap-typeahead, twitter-typeahead, angular-ui-typeahead

I have scope values  in  controller.I need to display scope values in custom type ahead template.

But custom template will not access the controller values it always display empty.

In my scenario i need to display "scope.names" in custom templates. but it show empty .

How to display the controller values in custom templates.

**HTML:**

```
<div class='container-fluid typeahead-demo' ng-controller="TypeaheadCtrl">
    <h4>Custom popup templates for typeahead's dropdown</h4>
    <pre>Model: {{customPopupSelected | json}}</pre>
    <input type="text" ng-model="customPopupSelected" placeholder="Custom popup template" uib-typeahead="state as state.name for state in statesWithFlags | filter:{name:$viewValue}" typeahead-popup-template-url="customPopupTemplate.html" class="form-control">
</div>
```

**DEMO:**

https://plnkr.co/edit/HEf0lipdBP5ZyuciQsDo?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

You were actually having a mismatch in the JSON structure of `$scope.names` and what the `uib-typeahead` template requires. I changed the `names` array to match the structure template requires as follows.. and it works. If you want to do other-way-around, you can keep the array same and make changes to the template too!

```
$scope.names=[{
  name: "Alabama"
}, {
  name: "Alaska"
}, {
  name: "Arizona"
}];
```

[working plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/1l0Y8oD9TEPckCUB5egX?p=preview)

Comment: I need to display "$scope.states" in below "select location from drop down"

and $scope.names in below Custom List from controller

Comment: @CodeMan let me understand it correctly. You want to display two lists' items as one dropdown's values? So whatever we type in the input gets suggested by both the lists. Is that correct?

Comment: @CodeMan I can make it display but you won't be able to select anything from the list that we are displaying forcefully. If you want to be able to select from that list as well, you'd need to concat two lists and pass to the typeahead but then they won't appear seperate

Comment: any possible ways to separate list